# What does $X_1,...,X_n $ mean in $X_1,...,X_n \sim N_p(0,\Sigma)$ (iid)?

Tags: random-variable

What exactly does $X_1,...,X_n$ mean in $X_1,...,X_n \sim N_p(0,\Sigma)$ (iid) ?

I am confused, since what I imagine is that the variables $X_1,...,X_n$ are the columns of a dataset? But From the fact that $N_p$ has index $p$, there are only $p$ variables and hence columns.

So, are $X_1,...,X_n$ rows? Are they datasets each containing $p$ variables/columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $X_i$'s are independent random Gaussian vectors, each $X_i$ being of dimension $p$. Once observed, they can be stored as an $n \times p$ matrix but this does not help with their mathematical definition.

Comment: So the dataset consists of n columns and p rows?

Comment: @Marina N rows and p columns.

Comment: It could be either, it is a matter of convention.