# Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ (iid), how do I interpret the sample mean $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}X_i?$

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

Let $X_1,...,X_n \sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ (iid). From [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504685/what-does-x-1-x-n-mean-in-x-1-x-n-sim-n-p0-sigma-iid) I asked before, I understood that an $X_i$ is a gaussian vector, and each vector, once observed (say $n$ times), can be stored as a $n\times p$ matrix.

Now, how do I interpret the sample mean $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}X_i?$ In particular, how do you sum up $n$, $n\times p$ matrices. Is my reasoning wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $X_i$ is a vector with length $p$ and the sample mean will also be a vector of length $p$.  In particular, if we denote the elements of each vector as $X_i = (X_{i,1},...,X_{i,p})$ then the mean vector is:

$$\bar{X} = \Bigg( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,1},...,\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_{i,p} \Bigg).$$

Comment: This assumes that each $X_{i,j}$ takes a single value (1 obervation), right? What if we have $m$ observations?

Comment: Your question stipulates $n$ observations from a $p$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution.  If that is correct then each $X_i$ is a vector of length $p$ (i.e., it contains $p$ scalar random variables).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can't the $X_i$'s  be $m\times p$ matrices, given we have $m$ obervations for each of them? So $X_1,...,X_n$ would mean $n$, $m\times p$ matrices, given we observed all $X_i$'s $m$ times? Or this is not correct, as in when we write $X_1,...,X_n \sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$, this means that each $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$ is just $1$ obervation?

Comment: The notation $N_p$ usually refers to the [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) producing random vectors of length $p$ (and nothing in your question mentions a value $m$).  It is certainly possible to produce random matrices instead, but this is inconsistent with the notation used in your question.  From what you have written in your question, you should have $X_i \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

Comment: yes, I have written that $X_i\in \mathbb{R}^p$. But I also asked what would be the situation if these $X_i$'s were matrices? (I didn't mention $m$, but I did mention $n$ as in $n\times p$ matrirces)

Comment: If the individual observations are matrices then the sample mean will also be a matrix (with the same dimensions).

Comment: Maybe I am just interpreting the $\sim$ symbol wrong. Is the convention that when we write $X_1,...,X_n\sim N_p(\mu,\Sigma)$ (iid), it means "n independent _draws_ from a multivariate normal distribution with $p$ variables"? So they are _draws_ by default, and by convention it is needed to specify if each $X_i$ has $n$ observation? Sorry for these questions, I am a complete newbie in this space!

Comment: Okay, thank you for clarifying the matrix part. Can you add it in the answer maybe? That would be great

Comment: I am satisfied that my answer matches the details of the question, so I don't propose to alter it.  I hope the comments suffice.

Comment: Okay, that is fine. Thank you regardless!